# lastlog only showing results for single user

Tags: linux, centos, login

If I run `lastlog` with the option `-l` and a range, I get

```
# lastlog -u 1000-
Username         Port     From             Latest
nfsnobody                                  **Never logged in**
```

However, I specify a `uid` within the range, I get

```
# lastlog -u loris
Username         Port     From             Latest
loris            pts/34   160.45.11.110    Tue Jul 26 15:32:45 +0200 2022
```

The user is also not shown if I just run `lastlog` without any options - only a bunch of system users are shown.

Specifying a range used to work correctly.  Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  The problem occurs on CentOS 7.9.2009.

Comment: Are your users in `/etc/passwd` or though some other authentication scheme? It appears that `lastlog` uses the password file, not `getent`.

Comment: More correctly, `/etc/passwd` is used when a uid range is specified. `getent` is used when a username is specified.

Comment: The users I am interested in come from LDAP and are not in ```/etc/passwd```, but using a range to obtain them worked up until recently (a CentOS update may however have changed things).  Do you have a source for the information about ```/etc/passwd``` being used with a uid range?

Comment: I ran `strace lastlog -u 1000-` to look at system calls. I might have misread the trace. I use `sssd` to authenticate against AD and I do see the sss socket being opened.  I have enumerate turned off so a uid search would not turn up anything. Have you changed your `ldap` configuration recently?

Comment: As far as I know the LDAP config hasn't changed recently.  I now realize that specifying a range means that the actual existing UID have to be looked up somewhere before the ```lastlog``` database can be queried. Weirdly everything is working correctly on a second similarly configured server (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712138/getent-passwd-not-showing-ldap-users-athough-users-can-log-in).