# 'getent passwd' not showing LDAP users, athough users can log in

Tags: ldap, sssd, nsswitch, getent

I have an administration node running LDAP and a login node which uses LDAP on the other node to authorize users.  Users are able to log into the login node successfully.

When I run `getent passwd`, on the admin node I get all the users, both those from `/etc/passwd` and LDAP.  However, on the login node the LDAP users are missing.  Both machines are running CentOS 7.9.2009 and both have an identical `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  The only non-trivial differences between the two version of `/etc/sss/sssd.conf` is that on the admin node

```
ldap_access_order = filter,expire
```

is set, whereas on the login node the setting is

```
ldap_access_order = expire
```

but that seems to me irrelevant (the filter just contains a single non-root functional user which was only used when the system was set up).

Where else should I be looking to work out what the difference is between the two systems?

Comment: try to clear the `sssd` cache and run the test again

Comment: Clearing the cache has no effect on the problem.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: You were right. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to delete the `sssd` cache was indeed correct.  However, running

```
sss_cache -E
```

did not help.  I had to actually delete the relevant files with

```
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*
```